# Regex get all numbers before colon

Tags: php, regex

I have the folling string:

```
$string = "16,1-5,22-27&22:1&4:3"
```

I want to get all numbers before the colon and return an array with them. So for the given string i would get the following:

```
array(22,4)
```

Comment: `#(\d+):#` something like this should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
\d+(?=:)
```

**Code:**

```
$str = "16,1-5,22-27&22:1&4:3"; 

preg_match_all('/\d+(?=:)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO1gQ6/1)

Comment: Thank you, it works! And how do i get the string after the colon until another "&" is found?

Comment: For that you can use this regex: `/(?<=:)[^&]*/`

Comment: If it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Short and sweet, +1. @Filip According to the iron laws of SO etiquette, I'm allowed to [tell someone who has never accepted an answer about how it works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/). :) If this or another answer works, would you consider clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to say you accepted it? That's how the reputation system works here, accepting an answer gives reputation both to the answerer and to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This pattern also works without any issue, no need to use lookahead: `#(\d+):#`

```
<?php
$string = "16,1-5,22-27&22:1&4:3";
preg_match_all('#(\d+):#', $string, $out);
print_r($out[1]);//Array ( [0] => 22 [1] => 4 ) 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "16,1-5,22-27&22:1&4:3";

preg_match("/(\d)+:/", $string, $results);

print_r($results); // you will see what you want
```